# Python: Why does a lambda define the variable in an inline if?

Tags: python, lambda

Toying around with lambdas in Python I discovered that the following code is legal in Python 2.7.3 and returns the lambda:

```
x = lambda: 1 if x else 2
```

Why does the lambda define x when used in this way?

Edit: Python syntax is apparently too hard for me, see the accepted answer…

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to write `x = lambda` in Python. The only advantages of `lambda` over `def` are (a) you can use it in an expression, rather than a statement, and (b) you don't have to give it a name. The assignment makes it a statement, and gives it a name, so you've lost both advantages.

Comment: @arbarnet: brevity? I'd prefer lambdas for something like `f = lambda x: x**2 + 3*x + 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the lambda define x when used in this way?

It doesn't. The assignment `x = [any expression]` defines `x` to be `[any expression]`. In this case, the expression is `lambda: 1 if x else 2`, which evaluates to a function object without arguments, and it is that which `x` holds.

Comment: This can be proved by trying `x = lambda: 1 if y else 2` (assuming `y` doesn't already exist).

Comment: I just realised this (and came here to delete the question), but thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: @AndreasFrom You're welcome! There's no need to delete this question - it addresses a concrete question with clarity, and is a point of confusion that could reasonably recur.